# Get textbox from canvas

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas, wpf-controls

I have 3 TextBox objects as children of a Canvas object, I then have that Canvas object as a child of a larger Canvas.

The TextBox objects are set as children of the child Canvas so that I can drag them around as 1 object (the child Canvas) and interact with mouse events.

How do I get the text from the TextBox objects out of the child Canvas object?

I have tried

```
Dim newTextbox As TextBox = childCanvas.Children(0)
```

but I cannot cast from a Canvas to a TextBox.

Comment: Use a type cast, i.e. `Dim newTextbox As TextBox = CType(childCanvas.Children(0), TextBox)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get the text from the canvas like this

```
Dim text As String = childCanvas.Children(0).GetValue(TextBox.TextProperty)
```